# Grunt Uglify; script merging produces error

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

When 'grunt build' is run all the scripts are merged and minified. This produces a 'undefined' error because one of the scripts is missing a ; semicolon to properly end the script.

Basically we need such a option: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#separator
Which does not exist in grunt-contrib-uglify.

This error only appears if you have to do 'grunt build'.

Comment: I don't think that option exists in the `uglify` task, I'm not sure what you can do about it other than either add the semicolons manually or use the `concat` task in addition to the `uglify` task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your task `build` does, but assume it's something close to "running everything", like `$ grunt` by itself would do...

@jakerella is right, `uglify` doesn't feature a separator as `concat` does.

I would use `concat` to concatenate the scripts with a separator of your choice (`concat` lets you do that) and then use `uglify` to minify whatever script `concat` concatenated.